# mysql insert after delete fails because of "duplicate entry"

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a code with two mysql queries.
`DELETE FROM my_table WHERE user_id=some_number`
`INSERT INTO my_table (user_id, ... ) VALUES(some_number, ...)`

The field user_id is unique.

In rare cases the insert fails claiming a duplicate entry occurred. My first instinct leads me to to believe the DELETE didn't finish and now the insert is trying to insert and I'm getting a duplicate entry. Is this possible? How can I avoid this? Might there be a different explanation you can think of?

Update: The reason I'm deleting is because I want to delete all the data that I am not updating / inserting for the first time. Also, I think it is important to state that most of the data remains the same.

Comment: Is it possible that it is a race condition where two processes are running those two statements for the same ID concurrently?

Comment: you may be interested in REPLACE and INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE statements

Comment: it is possible that DELETE fails? is there some check after its execution?

Answer (score 4):

```
SET AUTOCOMMIT=0;    
START TRANSACTION;    
DELETE FROM my_table WHERE user_id=some_number;     
INSERT INTO my_table (user_id, ... ) VALUES(some_number, ...); 
commit;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use an UPDATE statement instead:

```
UPDATE my_table
SET my_column = my_value
WHERE user_id = some_number
```

Comment: You can (it's a MySQL variant on the `INSERT INTO` syntax). See here; http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert.html

Comment: Update won't delete the old data I wish to replace. Right?

Comment: Yes, `UPDATE` will replace the column data you specify. What data are you trying to replace?

Comment: @Noam: Can you post the exact queries you are running? Also all the fields that the table has?

Comment: I had the same issue, this seems like the best way to solve this issue, Insert / delete is a bit hackish

Answer (score 1):

You could always try a COMMIT after the DELETE to make sure its completed.

Comment: I just need to add another query with "COMMIT" to try that? If there are slow other queries will it wait for them also or can I just ask to wait for the delete to finish?

Comment: Yes, you can do the commit by itself.  From what you've posted of your code is shouldn't really be needed, but it would force the issue of getting the first statement to complete.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you `DELETE` and then `INSERT` the same `user_id` and not just `UPDATE` the row?

Comment: Because I want to delete all the data that I am not updating / inserting for the first time, and I'm no updating all the rows with the same data. Each new row/updated row will have different data.

Comment: Because situations can be different @ypercube

Comment: @Velaro what do you mean?

Comment: Updating sometimes can be confusing (more logic must be implemented, foreign keys may be linked to records which have to be deleted or updated), so its simple to delete and insert. It's my case actually, we delete and insert records in transaction, hovewer mysql sometimes complains in dublicate entry, I'm stub

Comment: oh, just saw, that you suggest on concrete field. In this situation why not to just update?(yeah, sure). But think about general case @ypercubeᵀᴹ

Comment: @Velaro I still don't understand what a general case would be. If I want to change some data about a user, I will update the row that is related to that user, updating only the columns that need change. Why should I delete all the user data and insert them again (possibly without changing some of them)? This is more work, including Foreign Keys. Not to mention possible triggers.

Answer (score -2):

This happens because the query are treated as two single transaction, so the order of execution is not guaranteed. The effect you are describing is because the insert is processed before delete. You should change the query logic or perform both queries in one single transaction.